ApiException when Creating Pod with Kubernetes Java Client
I am encountering an issue while trying to create a pod in Kubernetes using the Java client library. Below is the code snippet I am using:
package org.example;

import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.Configuration;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Container;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1ObjectMeta;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Pod;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1PodSpec;
import io.kubernetes.client.util.Config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class KubernetesPodCreation{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ApiException, IOException {
        ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

        CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();

        V1Pod pod = new V1Pod();
        pod.setMetadata(new V1ObjectMeta().name("hello-pod"));
        pod.setSpec(new V1PodSpec()
                .containers(List.of(new V1Container()
                        .name("hello-container")
                        .image("nginx"))));

        api.createNamespacedPod("default", pod, null, null, null, null);
    }
}

However, when I run this code, I am getting the following ApiException:
Exception in thread "main" io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: 
    at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:973)
    at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:885)
    at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.createNamespacedPodWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:10251)
    at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.createNamespacedPod(CoreV1Api.java:10203)
    at org.example.KubernetesPodCreation.main(KubernetesPodCreation.java:32)


I have tried to troubleshoot the issue by checking Kubernetes cluster status, authentication, permissions, and namespace existence, but I haven't been able to resolve it yet.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this ApiException? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You don't seem to have included details on what the exception actually is; do you have anything more than what you've shown?  Where is this code running, and how does it get Kubernetes credentials?
